# No persister error using NHibernate with ASP.NET, unit tests work correctly

Tags: c#, nhibernate, webforms

I've got an interesting error with an ASP.NET webforms application I've been working on. I am using NHibernate (regular, not fluent), connecting to an sqlite database, with the following mapping and configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>    
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SQLiteDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=C:\Path\To\Database.db;Version=3</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
    <property name="query.substitutions">true=1;false=0</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

There are a number of entities, but the following is a simple example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="XBMC.Data"
                   namespace="XBMC.Data.Model.Domain">
  <class name="Genre" table="genre">
    <id name="Id" column="idGenre" type="int">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="Name" column="strGenre" type="string" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

This file is configured as an Embedded resource. This goes hand in hand with:

```
public class Genre : IRecord
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

There is also an `NHibernateHelper` class which is used to grab a session (I've gleaned most of this from http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/your-first-nhibernate-based-application.aspx which is a fantastic tutorial on getting started with NHibernate).

```
public class NHibernateHelper
{
    private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

    private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
    {
        get
        {
            if (_sessionFactory == null)
            {
                Configuration config = new Configuration();
                config.Configure();

                config.AddAssembly(typeof(IRecord).Assembly);

                _sessionFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
            }

            return _sessionFactory;
        }
    }

    public static ISession OpenSession()
    {
        return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }
}
```

So far so good. I've been following a test-driven-development approach, and have some test-cases like the following:

```
[Test]
public void CanLoadGenre()
{
    using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
    {
        Genre g = session.Get<Genre>(759);
        Assert.That(g.Name, Is.EqualTo("Action"));
    }
}
```

These work fine (I'm using the latest version of NUnit with TestDriven.NET FWIW). I can see the SQL generated by NHibernate and everything looks perfect. The problems start when I try to use my library in an ASP.NET application.

What I would like to do is bind a ListView to an ObjectDataSource. To do this I've written a GenreProvider and this just gets a list of the available `Genre` objects. In the unit tests, this works fine. As soon as anything NHibernate-related gets run in the ASP application, I get `NHibernate.MappingException: No persister for: Genre` exceptions thrown and everything goes awry.

Specifically, it fails on the following line (the return statement):

```
using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
    return session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T).Name).List<T>();
```

(This is in a generic Repository class - however it works perfectly during unit tests).

So in summary: NHibernate seems to be working correctly during my unit tests, but fails when used in an ASP application. I'm confident that it is a problem in my configuration, but have scoured Google for 'no persister' errors (solutions have included ensuring the 'Embedded resource' setting for mapping files, various combinations of `AddClass`, `AddAssembly` etc on the configuration, setting `<mapping assembly="..." />` in my config etc, but with no success) but most likely cannot see the wood for the trees.

Can anyone shed any light on this and stop me from going insane? (I can post more code if needed, have held back to prevent information overload!)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this in your `hibernate-configuration` file (or indeed your `web.config` if thats where it lives)

```
<property name="current_session_context_class">web</property>
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. I also had to add a HttpModule to my web application - for anyone else with this problem, a good guide on how to properly get NHibernate up and running with ASP is here: http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Configuring-NHibernate-with-ASP-NET.aspx.